# How use xPath in JS + WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, xpath, webdriver-io

Piece of my code HTML:

```
<span class="c-extselect__label js-label">Some text 1</span>
<span class="c-extselect__label js-label">Some text 2</span>
```

I would like to write xPath which click on one of them two spans.

I know that works it:

```
browser.click(`//span[contains(text(), "Some text 1")]`);
```

But I would like to click according to "variable" which will be equal once "Some text 1" and nest time will be equal "Some text 2".

I've tried this:

```
browser.click(`//span[contains(text(), ${item})]`);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try: `//span[contains(text(), '${item}')]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an apostrophe around `${item}` to make the xPath expression valid: `//span[contains(text(), '${item}')]`